# What would be the best way to call shell script or python from Node JS?

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, python-3.x, wsadmin

My use case is,  I am building a web portal with Angular , Node and MongoDB, and now I have to call python which in turn runs some wsadmin commands.

Usage of this portal is not gonna be heavy. 
All these runs on same Solaris host .

Appreciate your response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

For example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('python test.py',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Would it provide the output from the script as well?